# Time complexity nested loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I'm having a hard time understanding algorithm analysis, especially the following example:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n^3; i = 2*i){
  for (int j = 6*n; j > 0; j = j-2){
  }
}
```

So my understanding of this is that the outer loop is `O(nlogn)` as **i** is multiplied by a constant amount, I'm unsure if the `n^3` makes any difference or not.

The inner loop confuses me the most though. I think it's `O(n)` as **j** is decremented by a constant amount but I'm uncertain whether the `6*n` and the `j > 0` have any influence.

If i'm correct then this entire algorithm would be `O(nlogn)`? Uncertain how to express the time complexity `T(n)` of this though.

Any insights would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Note that `^` is the XOR operator in most programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outer loop is not `O(nlogn)` - since `i` is multiplied in 2 every loop, it goes: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32... this means that it will take a log(n^3) steps for `i` to reach n^3 (the base of the log is 2).

More formal: `O(log(n^3)) = O(3logn) = O(logn)`

In the inner loop `j` is initialized to `6*n` and goes down in steps of 2. This means that it'll take 6n/2 steps for `j` to reach zero.

More formal: `O(6n/2) = O(3n) = O(n)`

So the complexity of the code section is `O(n) * O(logn) = O(nlogn)`

Comment: Sorry, do you mind elaborating? Still a bit confused

Comment: @Dan_JAVA_SQL can you be more specific: which step in the process is unclear ?

Comment: The outer loop makes sense now, what would have to be different for the outer loop to be O(nlogn)? Why are you dividing 6n by 2? Thanks

Comment: The only thing that is not covered is your question in the comment above: "what would have to be different for the outer loop to be O(nlogn)?". This question is a bit vague. I guess that if you'll run the outer loop inside another loop that takes `n` steps...

Comment: Great this is all starting to make sense! the only thing I still don't quite get is "since i is multiplied in 2 every loop, it goes: 2, 4, 8, 16, 32... this means that it will take a log(n^3) steps for i to reach n^3" wont it take log(n^2) as it goes 2, 4 ,8...

Comment: @Dan_JAVA_SQL no, `2` is the base of the log. try picking up an `n` as an example and run it with real numbers - it would probably make more sense then.

Comment: Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.